# ServiceStack + Swagger-UI [Api] Attribute Usage

Tags: servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

I must be daft, but I cannot figure out what the usage of the [Api] attribute actually does for [ServiceStack's SwaggerFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API).

Not tagging [Api] doesn't seem to influence whether or not the api shows up in Swagger and I cannot find a description rendered anywhere when using it like [Api("Service Description")]

My usage is like this:

```
[Api("Monkey Service Description")]
[Route("/zoo/monkey/{Id}", "GET", Summary = "Get MonkeyDocument by Id", Notes = "Returns a MonkeyDocument based on Id")]
public class GetMonkey : GetAnimal, IReturn<MonkeyDocument> // GetAnimal Has Id property
{
}
```

In Swagger-UI, the results show up on the page when expanded as:

```
/zoo              Show/Hide List Operations Expand Operations Raw

 + GET /zoo/monkey/{Id}                  Get MonkeyDocument by Id
      Implementation Notes
      Returns a MonkeyDocument based on Id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ApiAttribute` is no longer used in any Swagger-related functionality. The only usage of it I could find is related to the [metadata page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceMetadata.cs).

Your use of `RouteAttribute` to describe the service endpoint is the correct way to document your routes in Swagger. You can browse the source of [SwaggerApiService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/SwaggerApiService.cs) and [its unit ests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/SwaggerFeatureTests.cs) to learn more about what attributes, etc., can be used to document your APIs in Swagger.

#### Edit

Actually, as mentioned in the comments, the ApiAttribute `Description` value is being returned to the Swagger UI client. e.g. the JSON sent back from the initial Resources request looks something like:

```
{
  "swaggerVersion":"1.1",
  "basePath":"http://localhost/api",
  "apis":[
     {"path":"/resource/zoo","description":"Monkey Service Description"}, ...
  ]
}
```

This particular `description` value is separate from the `Route` attribute description values, which are rendered in the Swagger UI and are returned from a separate Ajax request. The `ApiAttribute` description values, though they are returned to the Swagger UI client and stored in a `SwaggerResource` object in swagger.js, don't seem to be displayed on the screen in any way. At least with the current version of Swagger used by ServiceStack.

Here's a screen shot that shows how the Api and Route attributes are used on the Metadata page for a given DTO. I set up two Routes for the same DTO class to show the difference:

[image]

Comment: The MetaData and Swagger were unified.  SwaggerResourcesService.cs  calls GetDescription from ServiceMetadata.cs.  I can see my descriptions being rendered to the json results from the SwaggerResourcesService, can't see how it influences anything in Swagger-UI when rendered to the page, so am unsure of the purpose.

Comment: Thanks esker, that's the conclusion I've come to too, but where/how is it used otherwise?  There must be some advantage to it or I can't see why Mythz would've added it into ServiceStack.  He's a really clever guy :)

Comment: I added a screen shot that shows how the Api and Route attributes are used differently on the Metadata page. Basically the Api attribute provides a higher level description than the Route attribute.